# an added reference doesn't appear in the list of my .net project references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I have a web application developed under Visual Studio 2005. I have a dll (home made) that I need to add as a reference to my project. I do "Add reference", the dll is added to the Bin folder but It's not added to the list of the references ! So the project doesn't compile. Could you please tell why the dll is added to the Bin folder but it's not added to the list of references of the project? Many thanks !

Walloud

Answer (score 0):

If your "home created" assembly targets a framework newer than .NET 2.0, you won't be able to add a reference to it in a .NET 2.0 project in Visual Studio 2005.

Make sure your project for the DLL you created targets .NET 2.0, and not a newer framework, such as 3.5 or 4.0.

Since VS 2005 didn't know about the newer frameworks, you don't get proper error messages about this (from what I recall, though I no longer have a copy to test), which is likely why you're confused.

Comment: Hi Reed ! Thank you for replying to me. In fact, I did the same thing on my machine and it worked. Now My colleague face this problem and he asked me to help him as everything is fine on my machine. I gave him the same dll i am using but it doesn't work !

Comment: @Walloud Is he getting an error message?  Any feedback at all?  Same versions, etc?

Comment: No he's not getting any specific error message. Just the code doesn't find the dll when it calls it .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. I was working on an XP virtual machine and it appears that there is some issue with it. When I used a real XP machine it worked !